# Degradation in Latency for Synchronous usage with play 2.3.8

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.3

I have built Highly Synchronous REST API Service over play 2.3.8 in Java
And I am running stress testing over the Service. 
The Service behaves strange even with load generated with 5 threads calling service syncronously.

**Test Setup:**
Play service : 2 core CPU & 3.75 GB RAM
Load generator : 2 core CPU & 3.75 GB RAM

**Below are my observations:**
1. The Play service starts with a latency of 40ms
2. The Latency of service gradually degradeds to around 100ms in 5 mins and continues degration to over 600ms
3. During this interval CPU and Memory utilization remains consistent at both Play server and Load generator.

**Any reason for gradual degradation of latency and how can this be fixed?** I am using Play recommented config for Highly synchronous application

```
play {
  akka {
    event-handlers = ["akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jEventHandler"]
    loglevel = WARNING
    actor {
      default-dispatcher = {
        fork-join-executor {
          parallelism-min = 300
          parallelism-max = 300
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: And what your REST service does? DB access? Remote access to other services? How many req/s it can process? How does it behave without the high synchronous config?

Comment: The Service does lots of DB intensive ops, it also depends on third party service for every request.  Without  high synchronous config I haven't tested intensively but it gave timeouts initially due to which I changed to high synchronous config

Comment: req/s :  initial 125 . and degrades to 25-30 ... I have only 5 threads Making request Synchronously so req/s depends on latency .. as latency reduces so does req/s

Comment: If you're doing intensive db operations, how do you know the db isn't the bottleneck? Or the remote service for that matter.

Comment: Have monitored other services as well. DBs could support over 40K ops/sec per sec however the load generated by service was max 3K ops/sec. Did I miss any thing in play's Config